# Prove that $\sec(\pi/7)\frac{(4-\sec^2(\pi/7))}{(2-\sec^2(\pi/7))}=4$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $$\sec(\pi/7)\frac{(4-\sec^2(\pi/7))}{(2-\sec^2(\pi/7))}=4$$

MY ATTEMPT: I thought of writing $\sec^2(\pi/3)$ in place of 4 and $\sec^2(\pi/4)$ in place of 2 in the question, and then applying $\cos^2(A)-\cos^2(B)=\sin(A+B)\sin(B-A)$, but it didn't helped (it made the question more complicated).
I also tried converting the whole question to $\tan$, but it didn't helped too.

Can anyone help me out with a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sec(\pi/7)\frac{(4-\sec^2(\pi/7))}{(2-\sec^2(\pi/7))}
&= \frac{1}{\cos(\pi/7)}\cdot\frac{4\cos^2(\pi/7)-1}{2\cos^2(\pi/7)-1}\\
&= \frac{2\cos(2\pi/7)+1}{\cos(\pi/7)\cos(2\pi/7)}\\
&= \frac{2\sin(\pi/7)(2\cos(2\pi/7)+1)}{(2\sin(\pi/7)\cos(\pi/7))\cos(2\pi/7)}\\
&= 4\frac{\sin(\pi/7)(2\cos(2\pi/7)+1)}{\sin(4\pi/7)}\\
&= 4\frac{(\cos(2\pi/7)\sin(\pi/7)+2\sin(\pi/7)\cos^2(\pi/7))}{\sin(4\pi/7)}\\
&= 4\frac{(\cos(2\pi/7)\sin(\pi/7)+\sin(2\pi/7)\cos(\pi/7))}{\sin(4\pi/7)}\\
&= 4\frac{\sin(3\pi/7)}{\sin(4\pi/7)}\\
& = 4 
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\cos\left(7\cdot\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}7\right)=-1$ for any integer $r$

$7x=(2r+1)\pi\implies4x=(2r+1)\pi-3x$

$\implies\cos4x=-\cos3x$

$\iff8c^4+4c^3-8c^2-3c+1=0$  whose roots are $c_r=\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}7, r=0,1,2,3$

But $r=3\implies c_3=-1$

So, the roots of $$0=\dfrac{8c^4+4c^3-8c^2-3c+1}{c+1}=?$$

$c_r=\cos\dfrac{(2r+1)\pi}7, r=0,1,2$

Now replace $c_r=\dfrac1{s_r}$ and simplify

Comment: How can I simplify $8c^3-4c^2-4c+1$ to $s\frac{4-s^2}{2-s^2}$? How to even introduce the denominator in the former?

Comment: @user_1729,   Set $$c=\dfrac1s\implies8-4s-4s^2+s^3=0\iff s(4-s^2)=4(2-s^2)$$